# Deactivate AlertDialog "OK" button till a text is typed on the EditText of the AlertDialog view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

In android studio I need to deactivate the positive(OK) button of an `AlertDialog` until the user types into the `EditText`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a custom alert dialog, then apply your logic.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_xml, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(mView);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setCancelable(false);

        final AlertDialog alertDialogAndroid = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();

        final TextView tv_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        final EditText et_message = mView.findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        final Button bt_ok = mView.findViewById(R.id.bt_ok);
        final Button bt_cancel = mView.findViewById(R.id.bt_cancel);

        tv_message.setText(message);

        bt_ok.setText(ok_text);
        bt_cancel.setText(cancel_text);

// set on text change listener and enable buttons as per your choice
et_message.set....

        bt_ok.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            alertDialogAndroid.cancel();
            if (callback != null) callback.onSubmit("");
        });
        bt_cancel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            alertDialogAndroid.cancel();
            if (callback != null) callback.onCancel();
        });

        alertDialogAndroid.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code hope it will help you

```
 bt_ok.setenable(false);
```

and enable it on text change

```
bt_ok.setenable(true);
```

Comment: Worked with charm :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should create a custom alert dialog in your layout folder.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Then a layout inflater for the edit text given above so that our alert dialog will be able to show and get the text written inside.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater= this.getLayoutInflater();
final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

After that, we need to create an alert dialog. What is necessary here is to specify the edit text with `setView()` function by passing the final view we created. Since you do not have a cancel button, we do not need to call `builder.setCancelable(false)` here.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
    //Whatever you would like to do after pressing the OK button.
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

In order to get the OK button, we need to call through the dialog's `getButton()` function. Remember you need to call `setEnabled(false)` so that it will be disabled by default.

```
Button button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
button.setEnabled(false);
```

The last step is to add a text watcher to the edit text so that we can be informed when anything is typed.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (editText.getText().length() > 0){
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

The final code in a function should look like this:

```
public void getAlertDialog() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            //Whatever you would like to do after pressing the OK button.
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        Button button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (editText.getText().length() > 0){
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```